# How can we show the parent form after showing the report Form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6-migration

I have a problem in showing the parent form and report form at the same time.When user click on the parent form for print it should pop up with yes or no button when user click on yes button it should print the form screen shot image,if we click "No" button it should show the crystal report.

When we click 'No' button it should show the crystal report.So to show the messagebox i have done like this 
me.hide()

```
if MsgBox('Do you want to print screen shot image?') then 
'Print screen shot image
me.Show()
else
'Show CxReport
me.Show()
end if
```

When I Did like this the parent form is strucking and unable to perform operations.

Comment: Do you use something like TopMost or ShowDialog?

Comment: I didn't used any of the above you mentioned. :-(

Comment: Are both `Forms` opened at the time, the `MessageBox` appears?

Comment: first form1 will be opened then msgbox will be showed when we click a button in that form.Based on the reponse from the msgbox I am doing the operations .

Answer (score 0):

It's not standard practice to hide a form when showing a dialog. Completely remove the me.hide and me.show lines and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is an old one and you probably have figured it out by now, but I thought I would add an answer for future reference. All `Forms` have a [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) and [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) Event that you can attach a handler to in your creating Form. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to say.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
        If MsgBox("Open Report?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Dim frm2 As Form2 = New Form2
            AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf ReportClosing
            frm2.Show(Me)
        Else
            Me.Show()
            'Do your work for printing form here
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ReportClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        'Remove handler to prevent memory leaks
        RemoveHandler DirectCast(sender, Form2).FormClosed, AddressOf ReportClosing
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I Found the way to get the access the parent Page hiddenField Value as given below

```
function getParentPageHField() {
    var parentPageHField = window.opener.document.getElementById('hSelectedStandard').value;
    document.getElementById('hStandard').value = parentPageHField;
}
```

Thanks for your inputs :-)